# How to manual update a private WordPress plugin from free to pro version

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have a wordpress plugin in my wordpress repo. It's a free version. There are some features that are only available in the pro version of the wordpress plugin.
I put a download link from where users need to buy the **Pro version**.

Now I want such a way that when the user uploads the pro version it will update the codes of the free version and add the new features/functionality to the free version. It's a manual upload.
How to achieve this with code/plugin development? give an idea.

Comment: Your requirement isn't perfectly clear. Do you want to replace your free version's code with the pro version's code when your user uses WordPress core to install your pro version from the zip file you sold to your user? What do you want to happen later if you issue an update to the free version and your pro customer updates it? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Do you want to replace your free version's code with the pro version's code when your user uses WordPress core to install your pro version from the zip file you sold to your user?    YES

Comment: What do you want to happen later if you issue an update to the free version and your pro customer updates it ?  Then it should not be update, pro version can only be updated by manual upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way that might work.

- Give your free plugin version numbers like 1.1.2 etc.
- Give your paid one version numbers like 21.1.2 etc (20 greater than the free version).
- Give them exactly the same name and other metadata values that go into readme.txt and the toplevel .php file.
- Put the free one in the w.org repo. Distribute the paid one as a .zip.

Installing the paid version (via the upload button) will overwrite the free one. And because the paid one has a higher version number than the one in the repo, your customers won't get pestered to upgrade it, and autoupgrade  won't overwrite the free one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one question, If I put a different folder name for the Free and Pro versions it,  won't be replaced,  So I need to put the same folder name for the Free and Pro version, right  ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.